# Embedding multiple Lisp elements in a function programatically

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am messing around with web development and would like to do something like the following:

```
(defun col1 (&rest content) `((:DIV :CLASS "col1") 
                              (:COMMENT " Column 1 start ")
                              ,content goes here
                              (:COMMENT " Column 1 end ")))
```

where content is two or more lists returned by a function:

```
(defun two-list () ....)
```

that would return

```
'(:H2 "header")
'(:P "paragraph")
```

so that

```
(col1 (two-list))
```

would return

```
((:DIV :CLASS "col1") 
 (:COMMENT " Column 1 start ")
 (:H2 "header")
 (:P "paragraph")
 (:COMMENT " Column 1 end "))
```

I've tried using the values function, but it only seems to embed one list into the content area. Is it possible to do something like this? Thanks for the help lispers, I'm having a great time learning how to Lisp!

Comment: While this isn't an answer to your particular programming question, and questions asking for tools are off topic for StackOverflow, if you're going to be doing HTML generation based on s-expressions, you might be interested in taking a look at [CL-WHO](http://weitz.de/cl-who/), or some of [the other Lisp markup language](http://www.cliki.net/Lisp%20Markup%20Languages) out there.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using some cl-who, but mostly lml2 and cl-html-parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about two-list returns a list of elements you want to embed, like `((:H2 "header")(:P "paragraph"))`, then `col1` could be defined as:

```
(defun col1 (content) `((:DIV :CLASS "col1") 
                              (:COMMENT " Column 1 start ")
                              ,@content ; goes here
                              (:COMMENT " Column 1 end ")))

(defun two-list () '((:H2 "header")(:P "paragraph")))
```

Notice that I removed the `&rest` from col1. If you want to still have that you need to do `(apply #'col1 (two-list))` instead of `(col1 (two-list))`

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Your second solution works perfectly for me since I'd like to be able to add a bunch of stuff to the content area. Now off to read more about the @ symbol...

Comment: @gaauto If Sylwester's answer works for you (and your comment indicates that it did), you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to let others know that it worked for you.

Comment: If you look for documentation on an @ *symbol* you might have trouble finding it; the @ *character* has this particular meaning only in the context of the backquote and comma. http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm